# How to write a batch command in linux ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, batch-file, command, gdal

I have an installed library called Gdal which runs certain GIS commands.

This command runs for a single file

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:25832 INPUT_FILE OUTPUT_FILE
```

but I would like to run a batch command which iterates through all *.tif files so I don´t have  to write the name of each one (i´ve got 1300 files!)

I tried this in a .sh file...but it didn´t work

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.tif
do
  BASE=$FILE .tif
  NEWFILE=test/${BASE}.tif
  gdal_translate -s_srs EPSG:25832 $FILE $NEWFILE
done
```

could anyone show me how to do this?

yours,

Robert

Comment: What do you mean by `BASE=$FILE .tif` in line 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$FILE includes the `.tif` extension. Also `BASE=$FILE .tif` doesn't do what you think (it executes `.tif` with $BASE set to $FILE for the duration of the command).

You also have the difference between `-a_srs` and `-s_srs`. I don't know which you intended.

The end result is, I think, that you want to use `test/$FILE` as the output filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.tif; do
  gdal_translate -s_srs EPSG:25832 "$FILE" "test/$FILE"
done
```

(The quotes make it work with a path with spaces in it. Putting the `for` and `do` on the same line is a common way of writing it to save space.)

Comment: imho the best solution with the quoted variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....when I run your command I get the following error - ERROR 4: `test/dop20_col_32608000_5798000.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name. I have created the directory test with 777 permissions.

Comment: Perhaps you have the order of arguments wrong or something like that? It sounds like it's trying to read it rather than write to it.

Comment: this message doesn't make much sense with the script above. try to execute this script with `bash -e -x ./script.sh`. this will make the script exit on the first occuring error (-e) and display the commands executed (-x). with the debug information you can propably find the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your FILE variable already has .tif on the end, so you are appending .tif again.  Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in *.tif 
do 
  NEWFILE=test/${FILE}
  gdal_translate -s_srs EPSG:25832 $FILE $NEWFILE
done
```

Comment: Same here.ERROR 4: `test/dop20_col_32608000_5802000.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name....Just to make sure I have been understood. The command should create a new file with the same name as the old one, but put it in a different folder (/test)..Thanks for your help, Rob